# Design Question : How to build a Excel Spreadsheet as a Web Application?

Tags: database-design, web-applications

**Building a Web Based Excel**

In my workplace, my colleague are always struggling to update and maintain data in multiple spreadsheet and workbook. Most of the time, there will be multiple copies of excel file with different revision kept at different server location.

This is generally a problem because they end up messing up the integrity of the data as different people might update different excel workbook. Other time, when pasting certain data, the formulas are overwritten. Yes, I know the cell can be protected against alteration and so on but most users are accountant, office officer which are common computer user that doesn't really cares about it.

**Endless Loop**

They need to get the job done but disregarding of management regarding file's revision and location, they end up messing up their own life up. So countless meeting are held to organize who update what data on which spreadsheet and when. Most meeting don't end up well.

While ERP:SAP system is available in our company, not every single details is logged into the ERP system. Petty calculations, odd job tracking, and simple accounting uses excel in general.

So I thought why not design a web based excel where it will have basic excel functionality, subversion revision control, owner and collaborator control, email capability piggy back and all the goodness of centralizing all files in one location but accessible in all the networked PCs. Just like online Google documents but a scale down version where functionality can be added anytime due to scalable structure of web app nature.

**Design & Question**

The first question that comes to my mind is how will the database structure look like? What ERD is able to store data of almost infinite cell and spreadsheet? Is database model be suitable to store data or perhaps individual file such as comma delimited is a better solution to replace database? Suggestion and ideas are very much welcomed. Thank you all.

Comment: Why not just have one copy of the spreadsheet on a shared drive?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use [Google Docs](http://www.google.com/google-d-s/spreadsheets/#utm_campaign=en&utm_source=en-ha-na-us-bk&utm_medium=ha&utm_term=google%20spreadsheet).  Why reinvent the wheel?

But since you asked a database design question, I will try and answer it.

A spreadsheet is not like most documents.  That's why Lotus 123 became so popular.  Generally, you read the contents of a spreadsheet, keep the contents in memory as the spreadsheet is being manipulated, and save the contents of a spreadsheet all at one time.  There's no reason to access parts of a spreadsheet from a file.

Now, we know Microsoft uses a flat file structure for Excel.  You can do the same, although your spreadsheet format doesn't have to be as cryptic.  :-)

The simplest format I can think of for a spreadsheet file is a properties file.  Basically,

```
A1=23
A2=45
A3==A1+A2
```

It depends on what information you want to store for a spreadsheet cell.  How much formatting do you want to save.  Each cell could contain several pieces of information.  You could still use a properties file format like this:

```
A1={23,Ariel,right,...}
```

The spreadsheet file would probably contain a header that saved the properties of the entire spreadsheet.

```
Header={prop1,prop2,...}
```

This type of spreadsheet file would probably work well on all but the largest spreadsheets.